# Browser height DIV creates an extra space at the bottom

Tags: css, html, whitespace, footer

I am having a simple div with header,content and footer.Now my issue is that there is a gap at the bottom of my div.And if I resize browser window some more extra `white-space` is adding at the `bottom` of my div.

The entire leftContainer should be of `browser height`.

For example I need something like [this](http://www.picmonkey.com/)(actually this is done n flash I want it to be done in HTML)

This is how it looks now:

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
html, body
{
     margin: 0; 
     border: 0 none; 
     padding: 0; 
          overflow: hidden;
}
html, body, #wrapper, #left, #right 
{
     height: 100%; 
     min-height: 400;
}
.leftContainer 
{
    width:308px;
    max-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #292929;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #292929;
}
.mainbody
{
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height:736px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
.header
{

    height: 40px;
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}

.footer 
{
    padding-left:20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: whiteSmoke;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="leftContainer ">
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="mainbody">
    <p>Body</p>
</div> 
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

I don't want the footer to be seperate it should be within its parent div(`leftContainer`)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UqJTX/3/embedded/result/)**

Comment: You have not closed div having class=leftcontainer

Comment: @Ankit-it's just a typo here.But its there in the demo.

Comment: Only ,you want leftcontainer to have height equal to body

Comment: Yes and the main body height should be set to 100% and overflow:hidden;

Comment: I think jsfiddle is having some white space there :) The absolute positioning should work. However the DEMO does not show a footer in my Chrome, 100% height for the mainbody makes it as high as the body (So header, mainbody,footer adds up together more than the body height)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding

```
position: relative;
```

To your .leftContainer and

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

to your .footer ? Should make what you want.

Take a look : http://jsfiddle.net/UqJTX/7/embedded/result/

Comment: @Boris-Thanks for your reply.I have tried this before.If you maximize the browser window you can see still there is some white space at the bottom.

Comment: absolutely no.That's what I am struggling as it's height is 100% so that it stretches to the browser height.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with shadows, they are added to length in some browsers, so try to put only side shadows and apply negative margin.

Comment: @Johnny-Eventhough I remove the shadows its the same.

Comment: Have you seen common pattern for footer, which is at the bottom of page? Take a [look](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/). For me it solved all problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top:0;
overflow:auto;
```

To your .leftContainer and

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

to your .footer ? Should make what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the width of each div in percentages. Total left container height is 100% then decide the height for the three divs (like header 10%, body 85% and footer 5%) with appropriate percentages. Mentioning the heights or widths in pixel is not suggestible.

Use `firebug` for easy debugging of HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

check out this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ScePQ/11/) it works properly

Answer (score 0):

Use this like `min-height:100%`

may it will useful to you